# Moving Wordpress website from Localhost to Server

Tags: wordpress, server, localhost

I have a problem with moving my wordpress website from Localhost to Webserver .. In the server, I have an old website (wordpress to) .. so when i finished uploading the website I edited the wp-options siteurl and wp-posts guid from "Localhost:4455/ruepress" to "mydomain.com/ruepress2" because i have already another website exactly in the public_html directory .. when i enter to my website it loads the page but some pictures doesn't appear .. and when i click on an articles it redirects me to the old website and it shows the coming soon page (because i made the old website on under-construct mode) .. so whats the problem ? i think the problem is in the siteurl but I changed it ?

Comment: you need to change all the references in the database as well. Images are stored using their full path rather than a dynamic path. Search for your title in google, there are a lot of tutorials about the subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 for:

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

However, if you do not wish to use that rout for any reason, I can suggest an easier option:

On your local site, install this plug-in:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Next, generate a Duplicator package (via the plug-in's menu on wp-admin dashboad).

Once the package is generated, download the two package files (installer.php and the archive/zip file) to some folder on your PC. Next, upload these two files to the live site folder where you wish to create the site. Next, open the following link in your browser:

http://{your_domain}/{folder}/installer.php

and follow on-screen instructions. Your site should get created and everything should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for the answer .. I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issue. You have to change all URLs in the database, not just `wp_options`, i.e. in post/page content, widgets, theme options. and more.

Try [interconnectit.com WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/). It's specifically made for this. And see  [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress), which mentions the same Interconnect script.

Use the developer tools in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) (or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)) or [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to check the path of the missing images before and after using the script.

Comment: Thank you so much .. i think i have to use the search replace Tool because the URLs in  Dev tools are correct .. the problem is in the URls stored in the database